# Sitecore 7.2 Command Configuration

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I'm trying to get a command working in a new instance of Sitecore 7.2.  The command that I've added lives in a different assembly than the main project for this web application.  I've added the full path to the file for the command, along with the name of the compiled assembly in the App_Config/Commands.config file.

In Sitecore, I've added the command template under the branches/user defined folder and entered the command name from Commands.config, in the Command field.  I've then added the command as an insert option on the appropriate item in Sitecore.

When I log on as an admin and click the command link under the Home tab in the top menu, nothing happens.  No error is generated and the pop-up window does not appear - just nothing.

Having configured commands many times before in earlier versions of Sitecore, I can't think of what I'm missing...  The only difference this time is that the file for the command is located in a different assembly.  Am I missing a step somewhere that is needed, in order for this to work?  Did something change in Sitecore 7.2?

Comment: Can you share how you have the command defined in your commands.config?

Comment: <command name="item:newsubsite" type="Common.Web.Sitecore.Commands.NewSubSite, Common.Web.SiteCore" />

Comment: just to rule out the obvious is your DLL named Common.Web.dll or Common.Web.Sitecore.dll?  Just want to validate the base namespace.

Comment: Also, are there any errors in your sitecore log file?

Comment: The DLL is named Common.Web.Sitecore.  I'm not showing any related errors in the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there was an error in the reference to the namespace.  Once I updated that, the code ran.  The frustrating thing was that Sitecore wasn't generating an error.  It just wasn't responding, at all.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar situation the other day.  I had a Visual Studio solution with just one **Class Library** project and one C# class in the project.  I wrote some code in that class, built the solution and moved the DLL into my Sitecore website's bin folder.  I tried running the feature in Sitecore and nothing happened.  I confirmed I was referencing the DLL appropriately.  I then used the debugger in my Visual Studio to attach to my process and sure enough, the method parameters that Sitecore was supposed to set in my method signature were not getting set.

After trying a lot of different things, I decided to add a **Web Application** to my solution.  I then moved the code from the Class Library to the Web Application and updated Sitecore to reference the Web Application DLL instead of the Class Library DLL.  All of the sudden, my method parameters were set and the rest of my code worked as expected!

So my suggestion is: if you have the code the in a **Class Library** right now, move it to a **Web Application** project and see if that helps.

Comment: So does Sitecore assume that the cs file containing the command code is living in the same project as the Commands.config file?  Whether or not that's the case, it seems like I should be seeing sort sort of an error.

Comment: It seems to be that Sitecore wants your code to come from a DLL in a Web Application project, not a Class Library project.  Seems very strange but that's what I've observed so far.